# Get index from a list of objects with one of the object's attributes

Tags: python, oop, arraylist

I have a list of objects and I'm trying to get one object's index in that list from an attribute of the object I have (e.g. name). Similar to something like the example below:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

def add_emp(name):
    employees.append(Employee(name))

employees = []
add_emp('Emp1')
```

Now I'm trying to get the index of *'Emp1'* in the list *self.employees* (here *'0'*). I tried this here:

```
print(employees.index(filter(lambda x: x.name == 'Emp1', employees)))
```

but he tells me that *'ValueError: < filter object at 0xblabla > is not in list'*. What do I have to change or is there a better option to handle this?

Comment: You could use the `enumerate` function, it returns an iterator of tuples in the form `i, o` where `i` is the index and `o` is the actual object.

Comment: @hkzl You have to iterate over it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well don't search for the filter itself, search for what the filter *finds*. For example, `next(filter(...))` instead of `filter(...)`.

But really better just use `enumerate`:

```
print(next(i for i, x in enumerate(employees) if x.name == 'Emp1'))
```

Or you could create a list of names and ask that for the index:

```
print([x.name for x in employees].index('Emp1'))
```

It's less efficient, though.

Comment: Both, your and @ettanany 's answer work perfectly fine, but this one does the job in a single line, so I took this as the accepted answer. Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 1):

Because [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) returns a filter object, an approach would be converting it to a list and take the element with index 0:

```
print(employees.index(list(filter(lambda x: x.name == 'Emp1', employees))[0]))
```

But, the best approach would be using [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
def get_employee_index(name):
    for i, e in enumerate(employees):
        if e.name == name:
            return i
    return -1  # for not found employee
```

**Output:**

```
>>> get_employee_index('Emp1')
0
```

Comment: The first approach, using the filter, actually didn't work for me because he complained about the *list index* being out of range. However the second option, which you and the others stated as being better anyway, worked perfectly. Thanks a lot!